# Will an SSD kill a PS3?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, hard-drive

A while ago I bought a PS3 super slim 12Gb, and I intended to put a 120Gb SSD (a Samsung 840 EVO) inside it. I purchased the mounting bracket etc and as all the guides I read said just slapped it in and then waited for all the files to copy over, or so I thought! In reality my PS3 died, no sign of life other that a light, nothing on the screen, no loading noises not even a fan.

So where did I go wrong? It's the first time I've ever done this and all I've read and watched are pretty light on the pre installation details.

Do I need to format to FAT32 first and partition the drive? Is there a step I've missed, or will the drive simply remain a console killer for life and need putting away?

Comment: What colour is the light? Do you have the RCA/Component cable that comes with the PS3 still? Since you are getting nothing on the screen, it might be that you need to reset your video output. Plug in with the RCA/Component cable and while off, hold the power button down until you hear a second beep. See if you get video output now.

Comment: I'm starting the process again with a new ps3 super slim as the other one got swapped by the store I purchased it from. Just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing this time around. I assume that as the software is all on the internal flash drive putting in an SSD wouldn't affect this? Or does the new drive take priority?

Comment: I didn't think you needed to do anything specific when swapping a drive, but apparently you do: https://www.playstation.com/en-nz/get-help/ps3-system-software/

Comment: That should give you enough to go on, when you figure it out feel free to post an answer detailing your steps. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently swapped a PS4 harddrive for a Samsung Evo and had to format the drive to FAT32. You then need to download PS firmware (the latest version), and put it inside a folder named PS3 which contains a folder called UPDATE.

PS3 -> UPDATE -> (your update file)

From there, start the PS but hold the power button. It'll boot in safe mode and allow you to follow the instructions and turn the SSD into a PS drive. Once it installs properly just use any backup drive (portable drive or USB) which you've saved your previous data onto via "Backup and Restore" in the PS settings and plug in it to your new SSD system and you should be able to restore from the backup.

http://www.techradar.com/us/how-to/gaming/how-to-upgrade-your-ps3-hard-drive-1285911

^good link to follow